# Parse Outgoing Emails (through Salesforce email composer) to change body's font style and embed a Signature

Tags: email, salesforce-id, emailmessage

I would like to know if accessing outgoing emails before they go out of the system is possible. We want to get rid of default Salesforce signature and embed one of our own in all the outgoing emails.

But I'm not sure if the EmailMessage records are generated before the email is sent out.
Any thoughts or knowledge on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by default Salesforce signature? This sounds like a use case for an email template and/or letterhead

Comment: Default Salesforce signature means the signature under each user profile. And yes, it is related to template. So, we are using Salesforce and gmail Integration. When, a rep sends an email with a template in gmail, they are getting 2 signatures. (1 from the gmail profile and 2nd from the Salesforce user profile)

Comment: I've worked with gmail and outlook integrations and I've never seen this problem. Can you not remove signatures from Gmail? By the way, are you using lightning?

Comment: Yes, we thought of removing signature from gmail which will work great once when rep send email for the first time. But then, when a customer will reply and rep will reply back to the thread they will have to add a signature manually. Which is a waste of their time. And Yes, we are using lightning.

Comment: Well, to my knowledge, your only choice is probably to eliminate the redundant signatures in your Salesforce templates. The only other route I can think of would be to bulid a custom email handler that you send to and that strips a string from the email before sending it again. This sounds like killing a fly with a hammer though. Custom emal components that handle templates--I've done one--are a lot of work and you have to work with a different, more limited, feature set than internal developers get.

Comment: Are you saying that we can create an outbound email handler to strip the signature?
Is it even possible? If yes, can you share any example? Because I have been looking after it like crazy but did not get anything.

Comment: I should have been clearer. You would have to send it to an inbound email handler to modify and forward. I think that's the only way you can get a reference to the emal body. You would have to save the send-to address in the body or the subject and extract it to forward to. Handling the send to address is the difficult part. Or you could conceivably embed a reference to the lead or contact that holds the email. This is how email-to-case works. I suspect people do things like this if they need to scan outgooing emails for forbidden content.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have any sample or documentation shows how to even start? Something that I can see would be really helpful.

Comment: Just serch for apex inbound email service. You'll need to use the outbound email service to send it after you modify it.

Comment: I have started looking into it. I will keep this post updated. Thanks

Comment: One question - As you say it is possible then is there any limitations related to it or any consideration that I should be aware of?

Comment: I can't think of any other than your having to send to a salesforce emal service address and then extract the actual email address to send to. Any attachments would have to be saved and then reattached in the outgoing message. It's a fair amount  of work, maybe 12 hours for an experienced developer, and adds potential points of failure to the action of sending an email.

Comment: So, as an expert, would you prefer this approach to be good? Or something that you would do? I'm asking this question because as you said there could be potential points of failures so, I am assuming they will be really hard to debug as well. 
Don't have much idea in the email area.

Comment: Sorry I meant **Would you advise this approach to anyone?

Comment: It probably has a use case for scanning outgoing emails for training or to catch something forbidden but in your case the technical cost seems a lot higher than it would be it you solved your problem declaratively by eliminating one of the signatures.

Comment: @Cleverlemming - Thank you for your guidance. It helped me alot.